# Devise recover password link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, forgot-password

I try to set devise recover password link in my layout view...
I try so:

```
= link_to "Забыли пароль?", new_password_path(resource_name), :class => "login-link"
```

but i get

```
undefined local variable or method `resource_name'
```

How can i render in layout forget password? link in rails view?

Also my model:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, 
         :token_authenticatable, :timeoutable
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
= link_to "Забыли пароль?", new_password_path('user'), :class => "login-link"
```

with 'user' or with whatever your devise model class is.